Is Facebook official SDK's are supporting or inbuilt with the Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)?
In our app, we log in using the official Facebook SKDs for Android and iOS. However, we received a report that a third-party malicious app could hijack our 0Auth Access token for our Android app. As a solution, we're considering using the PKCE method, and we can see that the Facebook API already supports that.
So, we want to know whether the official Facebook SDKs also support that or if they are already built with that functionality.
If not, will we have to have our own login flow to use PKCE?
